# Which files to upload on github?

Tags: github, gruntjs, bower, yeoman

I am new to frontend development, but I feel like I'm getting there. I'm currently creating a website for myself, however I still want to learn and do best practices. In that process I want to upload my project to GitHub.

I have created my initial project-framework with yeoman, package managed any js with bower, created a bower.json for any dependencies, compiled and minified my code with Grunt.

**Which files would make sense to upload to GitHub?** I don't think my entire directory would make sense?

My initial thought to upload:

> index.html
>
> main.css
>
> main.js
>
> bower.json
>
> gruntfile.js

Below is my entire directory created in Yeoman

> Gruntfile.js
>
> bower_components
>
> package.son
>
> app (directory)
>
> dist (directory created by grunt)
>
> test (directory created by yeoman(?))
>
> bower.json
>
> node_modules (directory created by yeoman)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your project basically includes source code(which are created by developers), management configuration file(like bower.json, package.json etc.). All of these files need to be put on github. Other files like node_modules/**, bower_components/**, which can be downloaded from internet should not be put on github. You may think about this situation, all the files which need to support your web application logic should be put on github. Other files which can be downloaded can be ignored. In another way, you create the project structure and init the git repository. Which files should be needed if other people clone this repository to their machine?

Comment: I've basically arrived at the conclusion that anything generated shouldn't be uploaded, while the remaining files should. I created a .gitignore through http://gitignore.io/ .. Thanks for the help